# Autofac scope in ASP.NET Core appears to differ between middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

When registering an object with Autofac and resolving in middleware and again in the MVC middleware via a controller, the instance is different. Instances are registered per lifetime scope.

I've popped a repro project here https://github.com/jakkaj/AutofacResolveIssue.

The app sets a value to the `IUserService` in the middleware, then try to read that value in the `ValuesController` later.

This same technique worked in older versions of ASP.NET with autofac. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 18):

Okay, so I made the mistake of injecting my dependency in to the constructor of the middleware.

You should inject dependencies into the Invoke.

The entire middleware object is singleton across all app instances!

Comment: Thank you for coming back and updating for this! I'm just getting familiar with the request pipeline and middleware in ASP.NET Core and have been fighting this issue for a couple of hours now.

Comment: There is more information about this here...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x   It Appears that Middleware implemented by implementing IMiddleware interface are created once per request and don't suffer from this limitation.

Comment: And to add for clarification that the usual Autofac way to work around injecting per lifetime scope instances with constructor injection and `Func<MyInstancePerScopeType>` (see autofac delegate factories) does not work either with middleware. But since the *method injection* does work, just need to remember that.

Comment: Another possibly significant thing was that middleware registration is supposed to be done between `app.UseRouting();` and `app.UseEndpoints()`.

At least this diagram implies that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order

Answer (score 0):

Change builder registration to use `SingleInstance()` insted of `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`, So that every dependent component or call to `Resolve()` gets the same, shared instance.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserService).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service") || t.Name.EndsWith("Repo"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .SingleInstance();
```

> **Single Instance**
>  This is also known as ‘singleton.’ Using single instance scope, one instance is returned from all requests in
>   the root and all nested scopes.
>  When you resolve a single
>   instance component, you always get the same instance no matter where
>   you request it.

Check the link for more details
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#single-instance